# how to test dialogflow nodejs in local?

Tags: node.js, session, dialogflow-es

I follow instructions https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow for sessionClient, can I use postman to test that ??

also I still get confused to use dialogflow nodejs,
for sessionClient

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent
```

what is the sessions/* meant ? is that for sessionId ?

how to get SessionId for that API? if the sessionId we use random using uuid.v4() ??

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* use Postman to test it, you will need to deal with the authentication yourself, which can be a serious problem. The code should illustrate how to use the library, which will take care of many of the auth issues.

The portion of the URL labeled `{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}` means that you should replace all of that (including the braces) with the full session identifier. The first `*` in that is the project ID and the second `*` is the session ID. If you are doing this yourself then, yes, you are responsible for determining an appropriate ID - the only restriction is that it not be larger than 36 characters.

Comment: Anyway the request body on session should same like the sessionid on API? Right ?, And to run it , should I connect with express also ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking there. Can you update your question (or ask a new one) with what you're trying and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: I meant , I already follow the instructions of dialogflow nodejs example, and now should I hit the API to that dialogflow v2 API I asked ? And did I need express also for it ? Http requst